# XSL - Identity transform - change value of an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to change the value of RequestQueue elemt under "@sorregion name[.='default']" to "DEFAULT.REQUEST. I tried using the below identity template. Could anyone please help me with this dentity template. I would like to use identity template, only.
My xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@name[.='default']/QueueDetails/RequestQueue">
         <xsl:value-of select="'DEFAULT.REQUEST'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would approach this question is the same way that @Kirill Polishchuk did (+1 btw) and that is to override the identity transform only for the node that needs to change.

However, in your question you stated "*I would like to use identity template, only.*". If this is truly the case and you only want one template, you can do it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current()[name()='RequestQueue'][ancestor::SORRegion[@name = 'default']]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:text>DEFAULT.REQUEST</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would be curious to know though why you would want to use the identity transform template only. If you end up needing to modify more than just `RequestQueue`, it's going to get ugly fast.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. How can i change the attribute value,"default", alone? Rest all should be unchanged. SORRegion name="default" should be changed to SORRegion name="New"

Comment: @user1004770 - looks like Dimitre answered your question about changing the "name" attribute value here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036882/change-the-value-of-a-specific-attribute

Answer (score 2):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SORRegion[@name = 'default']/QueueDetails/RequestQueue">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>DEFAULT.REQUEST</xsl:text>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```