# How to indent the XML-Output of XSLT in Eclipse?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, auto-indent

I don't habe any ideas how to indent my XML-Output in Eclipse. Currently I have everything in one row.

What should I define beside indent="yes" in my XSLT?

Another problem is that I can not eliminate 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ after every DC-tag in my Output-XML.
It's really surprising that exclude-result-prefixes="dc dcterms "> only excludes dcterms, but not for dc.

Maybe someone has an idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<xsl:stylesheet  version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"


 exclude-result-prefixes="dc dcterms "> 

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />



Output XML:

                <dc:titel xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Fragebogen FB001</dc:titel>

    but it should be : 

          <dc:titel>Fragebogen</dc:titel>
```

Comment: To help with the namespace question, we'd probably have to see input, xslt and output documents, however, your original question, I think eclipse comes with various "editors" for different types - what editor does it use to show your XML-output? I assume you use '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>'?

Comment: @StefanHegny  yes exactly, I'm using that one <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />  I also tried another variations with xalan, but it didn't work. I still have the entire XML-Output in one row

Comment: Well, the output must of course declare the dc namespace if the element in the output requires it. If you don't want that, you must modify your xslt so that it removes namespaces - see the identity transform here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009758/xsl-identity-transform-change-value-of-an-element and modify <xsl:copy> to `<xsl:element name="local-name()">`